# Is this matrix well-conditioned?

Tags: matrices, condition-number

Take matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}1/3&1/4\\1/4&1/5\end{bmatrix}

I have calculated the condition number of A to be 245/3 (using l1-norm)

This means we may lose about 2 significant figures of accuracy (by the rule of thumb that for a condition number K(A) you lose log(K(A)) significant figures in accuracy).

Am I right to say this means the matrix is ill-conditioned because some of the values in the matrix are only to 2sf (e.g 0.25 and 0.2) or not because these values are actually to an infinite precision as they are fractions?

Comment: The condition number $C$ answers a different question. Assuming that $A$ is exact, it tells you that if the relative error in $b$ was $\epsilon$, the relative error in $A^{-1} b$ can be as big as $C \epsilon$.

Comment: @Maxim, we have roughly the same error when $A$ varies       https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnement_(analyse_num%C3%A9rique)#Cas_o%C3%B9_la_matrice_varie

Comment: To the OP. You lose only $2$ significand digits; then $A$ is well-conditioned.

Comment: @loupblanc I wouldn't call the lhs a relative error. The relative error $\delta_x$ (and thus the loss of precision) in $x = A^{-1} b$ can grow arbitrarily large when $A$ approaches a singular matrix. It is possible to give an upper bound for $\delta_x$, but with the assumption that the relative error $\delta_A$ is sufficiently small:
$$\delta_A < \frac 1 {\|A^{-1}\|_1} \supset
\delta_x \leq \frac C {1 - C \delta_A} ( \delta_A + \delta_b).$$

Comment: @Maxim , of course you are right. The error on $A$ is more "sensitive" than that on $b$.